# Output numeric from $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to take form input numbers in this format within $scope:

From:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.octHours">
```

Which renders:

```
"form.octHours": "12"
```

And convert the format to numeric where controller data looks like this:

```
{
  data: [12]
}
```

Which will be used in the controller like this:

```
$scope.form = {}; 

$scope.data = {
    datasets:[    
        data: [$scope.form.octHours]
        ]
 }
```

I have tried using input type="numeric" and escaping the quotes via javascript, but is there an elegant way of doing this? Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried injecting a filter into the controller then doing a string to it conversion?

```
 $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$parse('form.octHours').assign($scope,ParseInt($scope.form.octHours));
```